# Twilio messages not getting delivered until recently

Tags: node.js, sms, twilio, sms-gateway

I am using a free account. I am using SMS service for testing purposes. I got an number through which the messages were getting delivered successfully until recently. Since three days the messages are not getting delivered and the status of the message remains "sent" and not delivered. What could be the issue?

Comment: I'd recommend getting in touch with the [Twilio support team](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) with this issue. If you send them some message SIDs that haven't been delivered yet that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, if the delivery record cannot be received from carrier partner for some reason, the delivery status remains as "sent" . You can refer to the [details in this FAQ](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133467-Why-are-my-messages-status-sent-).

You may also experience limitation of sending SMS based upon location for example, [in India](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134167-Limitations-sending-SMS-messages-to-Indian-mobile-devices), all [SMS messages sent from Twilio phone numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) are categorized as “Promotional” , even if your message content is transactional.